# How to display binary images from Database to View using Model in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I am trying to display binary images from my database and I am able to retrieve  the binary data from database but in the **View** but the images is not displaying.

I tried to solve this problem by visiting most of the blog that is related to this question  but failed.
Can anyone help me please?

Here is my Model class :

```
public class HotelRoomImage : MyBase
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public byte[] Image1 { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image2 { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image3 { get; set; }
    public int HotelRoomId { get; set; }

   public bool SelectById()
    {
        Command = MyCommand("select id, image1, image2, image3, roomId from RoomImages where id = 1");
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Id);
        MyReader = ExecuteReader(Command);
        while (MyReader.Read())
        {
            Id = Convert.ToInt32(MyReader["Id"]);
            Image1 =(byte[])MyReader["image1"];
            Image2 = (byte[])MyReader["image2"];
            Image3 = (byte[])MyReader["image3"];
            HotelRoomId = Convert.ToInt32(MyReader["roomId"]);

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
  }
```

My Controller Action:

```
  public ActionResult Viewimages()
    {
        HotelRoomImage ri = new HotelRoomImage();
        ri.SelectById();
        return View(ri);
    }
```

Here is the view for my Action:

```
@model UploadImageMVCApp.Models.HotelRoomImage
 <div class="form-group col-md-4">

                @{
                    if (Model.Image1 != null)
                    {
                        var imageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Image1);
                        var imageSrc1 = string.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", imageBase64);
                        <img src="@imageSrc1" alt="" width="400" height="400" />
                    }
                }
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                @{
                    if (Model.Image2 != null)
                    {
                        string imageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Image2);
                        string imageSrc2 = string.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", imageBase64);
                        <img src="@imageSrc2" width="400" height="400" />
                    }
                }
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                @{
                    if (Model.Image3 != null)
                    {
                        string imageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Image3);
                        string imageSrc3 = string.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", imageBase64);
                        <img src="@imageSrc3" width="400" height="400" />
                    }
                }
            </div>
```

Comment: your image binding code is correct..but implementation is wrong.....

Answer (score 0):

**Model Class**

```
public class HotelRoomImage : MyBase
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public byte[] Image1 { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image2 { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image3 { get; set; }
    public int HotelRoomId { get; set; }
}

public class Model_Crud
{
 // image data should be there in varbinary(max) datatype column
 // fallowing method is to fetch the row with id=1.
   public HotelRoomImage SelectById()
  {
    HotelRoomImage model= new HotelRoomImage();
    Command = MyCommand("select id, image1, image2, image3, roomId from RoomImages where id = 1");
    // in the above select query i am hard coding id value as '1'......
    MyReader = ExecuteReader(Command);
    while (MyReader.Read())
    {
        model.Id = Convert.ToInt32(MyReader["Id"]);
        model.Image1 =(byte[])MyReader["image1"];
        model.Image2 = (byte[])MyReader["image2"];
        model.Image3 = (byte[])MyReader["image3"];
        model.HotelRoomId = Convert.ToInt32(MyReader["roomId"]);
    }
    return model;
  }
}
```

**Controller**

```
Model_Crud crud = new Model_Crud();
public ActionResult Viewimages()
{
    HotelRoomImage ri = new HotelRoomImage();
    ri = crud.SelectById();
    return View(ri);
}
```

Comment: Hey @Jilani brother using your given approach also give me the same result. **HotelRoomImage** is inhering from **MyBase** `class` to save Data and two retrieve and is working well but I am not able to display these images in **VIEW** and why it's not working I don't know.

Comment: your view code is correct..,but check in the browser inspect, whether the image tag src attribute is having any image or not ?...

Comment: Yeah My code is correct. It's now working well and I were actually doing wrong  when converting the binary data to insert. Now all the things are okay. Thanks for the time and suggestion.